I can't see messages in the database, How can I do it ? nodejs postresql
I share my code photo, What is the wrong anyone tell me ? I cant see my data in database. How can I fix it?  I can share client side code. I have 2 day for finish this project. I can share my github repo. I want save messages on database but I tried I havent solve, thanks for help
my  server code
chat component
